# Error: Unknown entity type requested -- when adding a product to DB

Tags: php, magento

I am creating a Module in Magento for customers to have multiple Wishlists.
I am creating the CRUD Model and now I want to add a wishlist to the DB.
Each Wishlist should have an ID, a name, a customerID, a sharing code and an updated date, as told in the db_schema.xml
When adding a Wishlist with a TestScript.php, it generates an error like:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
> Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException: Unknown entity
> type: VENDOR/WL\Api\Data\WishlistInterface requested
> in
> /var/www/html/app/code/VENDOR/WL/Model/WishlistRepository.php:44
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/TestScript.php(98): VENDOR\WL\Model\WishlistRepository->save(Object(VENDOR/WL\Model\Wishlist))
> #1 {main}   thrown in /var/www/html/app/code/VENDOR/WL/Model/WishlistRepository.php
> on line 44

Here is the content of my TestScript:

```php
 $params = $_SERVER; $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager(); 
 $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
 $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
 
 $wishlist =  $objectManager->get('VENDOR/WL\Model\WishlistFactory')->create();
 $repoWishlist =  $objectManager->get('VENDOR/WL\Model\WishlistRepository');
 
 
 $wishlist->setData('customer_id', 1);
 $wishlist->setData('wishlist_name', 'Christmas');
 $wishlist->setData('shared', 0); 
 $wishlist->setData('sharing_code',
 $wishlist->generateSharingCode()); 
 $repoWishlist->save($wishlist); 
 // replace the delete() by save()
```

My DB tables are not empty, I've put some examples entries.
I am using PHP 7.4 with Magento 2.4.3
What could I possibly do wrong? I've been on this one for hours now.. (modifié)

Answer (score 0):

An error occurred in the WishlistRepository.php file. If you can share details about the code in this file maybe I can help you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer :) The issue was resolved, I had to remove the EntityManager in my methods (save/delete/etc) inside Model > ResourceModel > Wishlist.php